# change font color across divs and spans

Tags: html, css

is it possible to change font color across several divs and spans with css?

For example, I have HTML that goes like this:

```
some text ### some text 
<div> some text in div</div>
some text 
<div> some text
  <span>some text</span>
</div>
some ### more text
```

Is there a way to change the color of the text to, let's say, red between the ### marks?

PS. The question is not about scripting, the question about the resulting markup/css itself.

Comment: No. The fourth `some text` isn't inside of any element, so there is no way to target it specifically.

Comment: Not without scripting or adding more elements

Comment: and neither is the first. that's what the question is all about.

Comment: CSS can't parse text. It is very specific and precise, so to answer your question, no.

Comment: @JasonGennaro adding WHAT elements?

Comment: @Blender i understand this. the question is whether there can be an overriding element that would work with both divs and spans inside, and that would override the colors of those divs and spans.

Comment: @UnoMeinAme, you could add a few `span`s around the text you want in red.  Not a great solution.  I would prefer scripting.

Comment: Can you provide an exact HTML example?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, so let's take the opportunity to go over some CSS basics:

This CSS will apply to all `div` tags:

```
div
{
    color: red;
}
```

This CSS will apply to all `span` tags inside a `div`:

```
div span
{
    color: red;
}
```

This CSS will apply to all `div` tags and all `span` tags:

```
div, span
{
    color: red;
}
```

If you want a CSS rule to apply to a certain section of code regardless of the elements in it, then you can put it in a wrapper, like so:

```
<div class="Wrapper">
    <!-- Lots of different tags in here -->
</div>
```

Then, you can apply this CSS rule to match all tags of any type inside a `div` with class `Wrapper`:

```
div.Wrapper *
{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: But the css Wrapper will not override the colors for the divs inside it, would it?

Comment: In CSS, the most specific rule always takes precedence. So, if the color for the `div`s was specified in the rule for `body`, then yes, it would, because a tag with a specific class is more specific than just a tag. But if you had another rule for `div.Wrapper div`, then that would apply over a rule for `div.Wrapper *`, since a `div` is more specific than any tag (*).

Comment: so the simple answer to my question as to whether it is possible to override those more specific classes with something general, is no, correct?

Comment: Actually, it is. If you want to force a rule to not be overridden, you can add `!important` one the same line, but after the semicolon of the rule.

Comment: so it would go to in the `.wrapper { color:red; !imporant }`?

Answer (score 1):

Always wrap the text like in your example in `span` tag. Don't throw the text like that. With that said, in general you can specify in .css file `color` property for `span`.

```
span{ color: Red }
```

But if you want specific span in a div to have a specific color then -

```
<div class="someClass">
    <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

In .css,

```
.someClass { /* properties for the div */ }
.someClass span { color: Blue; /* other font properties */ }
```